# Show that $L^2(0,1)=\operatorname{span}\{e^{2\pi inx}\}_{n\in \mathbb Z}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-series, lp-spaces

Q1) In a course, it's written that $L^2(0,1)$ is spanned by $\{e^{2\pi inx}\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$. How can I show it ?

Q2) Let $f\in L^2(0,1)$. Then we have Parseval equality, i.e.
$$\left\|f\right\|^2=\sum_{k=-\infty }^\infty \left|c_i\right|^2,$$
where $c_i$ are the Fourier coefficient. Is this convergence in the $L^2-$sense ? I mean, is $$\|f\|^2=\lim_{N\to \infty }\sum_{k=-N}^N\left|c_i\right|^2$$
in the $L^2-$sense ?

Comment: by definition, if $f \in L^2(0,1)$ then $ \|f\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2$ is finite so $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |c_k|^2$ converges absolutely, and $\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{k=-N}^N |c_k|^2 = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |c_k|^2$

Comment: Both question are answered in any standard book on harmonic analysis, or even basic functional analysis.

Comment: For showing $\{e^{2 i \pi n x}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ spans the whole Hilbert space $L^2(0,1)$, an usual method is to show the trigonometric polynomials are dense (for the $\|.\|_{L^2(0,1)}$ norm) in the step functions on $[0,1]$, so they are also dense in the continuous functions $C(0,1)$, and hence in $L^2(0,1)$ (which is defined at first as the closure of $C(0,1)$ for the $\|.\|_{L^2(0,1)}$ norm).

Comment: @user1952009: Sorry, but I don't understand. Since $f\in L^2$ of $\|f\|_{L^2}$ is finite. But I don't understand the rest. You mean that if $f(x)=\lim_{N\to \infty }\sum_{|k|=0}^N t_k(x)$ in the $L^2$ sense and that $\lim_{N\to \infty }\sum_{|k|=0}^N t_k(x)$ converge absolutely then $f(x)=\lim_{N\to \infty }\sum_{|k|=0}^N t_k(x)$ in the pointwise sense ? But I thought that $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$ doesn't imply that $f_n\to f$ pointwise, and that $f_n\to f$ pointwise doesn't imply that $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$...

Comment: We don't care of pointwise convergence, only of convergence in $L^2(0,1)$ norm ! And what I wrote in my 2nd comment. means that for any $f \in L^2(0,1)$ and for any $\epsilon >0 $ there is a trigonometric polynomial $f_\epsilon = \sum_{n=-N}^N c_n e^{2 i \pi n x}$ such that $\|f-f_\epsilon\|_{L^2(0,1)} < \epsilon$

Comment: And my 1st comment : $\{e^{2 i \pi n x}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal family of $L^2(0,1)$. But for any orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ of $L^2(0,1)$ : $f = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \langle f,e_n \rangle e_n$ so $\|f\|^2 = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |\langle f,e_n \rangle |^2$, and hence $\|f\|^2 \ge \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |\langle f,e^{2 i \pi n x} \rangle |^2$ (we get the equality once we proved $\{e^{2i \pi nx}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal basis, not only an orthonormal family, i.e. that it spans the whole space)

Comment: @user1952009: For parseval equality, the limit is not taken in the $L^2$ norms ! (it wouldn't have sense since the element of the sum are real numbers). By the way, $\|f\|^2$ is also a real number, not a function.

Comment: of course I know, what comment was unclear : "we don't care of pointwise convergence" ? I meant we don't care of the pointwise convergence of $\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N c_n e^{2 i \pi n x}$ to $f$ (or not), we only care of the $L^2(0,1)$ convergence $\|f-\sum_{n=-N}^N c_n e^{2 i \pi n x}\|_{L^2(0,1)} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$